# XSLT Iteration for similar repeating Holding Tags

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have an xml which looks like:

```
<RestrictedTicket>abc</RestrictedTicket> 
<FlightDetails1>
  <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber> 
  <ServiceClass>F</ServiceClass> 
  <CarrierCode>SL</CarrierCode> 
</FlightDetails1>
<FlightDetails2>
  <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber> 
  <ServiceClass>G</ServiceClass> 
  <CarrierCode>KL</CarrierCode> 
</FlightDetails2>
```

I am using an XSLT which looks like:

```
<RestrictedTicket>
<xsl:value-of select="RestrictedTicket" />
</RestrictedTicket>
<xsl:for-each select="FlightDetails1">
<FlightDetails>
<CouponNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="CouponNumber" />
</CouponNumber>
<ServiceClass>
<xsl:value-of select="ServiceClass" />
</ServiceClass>
<CarrierCode>
<xsl:value-of select="CarrierCode" />
</CarrierCode>
</FlightDetails>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The resulting output xml after transformation should look like:

```
<RestrictedTicket>abc</RestrictedTicket> 
    <FlightDetails>
      <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber> 
      <ServiceClass>F</ServiceClass> 
      <CarrierCode>SL</CarrierCode> 
    </FlightDetails>
    <FlightDetails>
      <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber> 
      <ServiceClass>G</ServiceClass> 
      <CarrierCode>KL</CarrierCode> 
    </FlightDetails>
```

I cannot use copy function here as I am doing many transformation of values in between. What I am looking to do is re-use the code for FlightDetails, so that I don't need to write it for 8 times (There are 8 repeating tags of FlightDetails like FlightDetails1, FlightDetails2...FlightDetails8 having similar child tags). Target is to have the holding tag changed from FlightDetails1 to FlightDetails and to avoid writing the same code 8 times for the 8 flightdetails data.

Answer (score 2):

The expression you are looking for, which will pick up the **FlightDetail1**, **FlightDetail2** (and so on) elements is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FlightDetails')]">
```

However, you mention about re-using code, so it is probably worth mentioning that such a problem as yours should really be tackled using the [XSLT Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own, this copies all nodes without change. However, this means all you then need to do is add templates for the nodes you do want to match. So, instead of using an **xsl:for-each**, you would be using template matching.

```
 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FlightDetails')]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FlightDetails')]">
      <FlightDetails>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </FlightDetails>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<Tickets>
   <RestrictedTicket>abc</RestrictedTicket>
   <FlightDetails1>
      <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber>
      <ServiceClass>F</ServiceClass>
      <CarrierCode>SL</CarrierCode>
   </FlightDetails1>
   <FlightDetails2>
      <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber>
      <ServiceClass>G</ServiceClass>
      <CarrierCode>KL</CarrierCode>
   </FlightDetails2>
</Tickets>
```

The following is output

```
<Tickets>
   <RestrictedTicket>abc</RestrictedTicket>
   <FlightDetails>
      <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber>
      <ServiceClass>F</ServiceClass>
      <CarrierCode>SL</CarrierCode>
   </FlightDetails>
   <FlightDetails>
      <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber>
      <ServiceClass>G</ServiceClass>
      <CarrierCode>KL</CarrierCode>
   </FlightDetails>
</Tickets>
```

See how you don't have to write any explicit code for copying the **CouponNumber** or **ServiceClass**, for example. This is achieved by using the template `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">`, so it is important this template is present in the XSLT.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But, I am still facing issues. Kindly advise. When I try to enter the piece of code in my existing XSLT as:
<RestrictedTicket>
   <xsl:value-of select="RestrictedTicket" />
   </RestrictedTicket>
   <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FlightDetails*')]">
   <FlightDetails>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </FlightDetails>
   </xsl:template>
   
It gives the resulting output as:
<RestrictedTicket>swer</RestrictedTicket>
<FlightDetails>
 abc 
- 
  1 
  F 
  SL 
  
  2 
  G 
  KL 
  
  </FlightDetails>

Comment: The XSLT given should provide the expected results. It is important though you have the template `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` in the XSLT. It is much better to use template matching in this way, rather than `xsl:for-each`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have modified the for-each and now it works perfectly. The modified xslt uses:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'FlightDetails')]">
```

instead of `<xsl:for-each select="FlightDetails1">.`

The rest of the code remains same. Thanks again for the help.